# How to get Nonce Token in Flutter mobile app?

Tags: flutter, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, flutterflow

I have use flutter to code for mobile app and get data all from @Woocommerce Store API [You can check here](https://developer.woocommerce.com/2022/03/25/store-api-is-now-considered-stable/)

but when we do Checkout it require Nonce Tokens description here:
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-blocks/blob/trunk/src/StoreApi/docs/nonce-tokens.md

When I write

```
wp_create_nonce( 'wc_store_api' )
```

this function in wordpress Function.php and I get Nonce Token but when I use that Nonce Token into flutter it wrong said invalid token.

I try to use

```
wp_create_nonce( 'wc_store_api' )
```

in flutter but I don't know how to call this function as this code is php.

Could you please give some help how to get this Nonce Token?